# Zod Optional validations base on inputted values

Tags: react-hook-form, zod

I have a form that has optional params based on how long they have been employed. If over 2 years, then we don't need to the previous employment fields.

```
const baseSchema = z.object({
  status: z.nativeEnum(LeaseEndEmploymentStatusType),
  name: zRequiredString("Enter the employer's name."),
  jobTitle: zRequiredString("Enter the buyer's job title."),
  phoneNumber: zPhoneNumber,
  grossIncome: z.number().nonnegative('Must be greater than 0.'),
  payFrequency: z.nativeEnum(LeaseEndIncomeIntervalEnumType),
  yearsAtJob: zYear,
  monthsAtJob: zMonth,
});

const formSchema = z.object({
  employment: baseSchema,
  prevEmployment: baseSchema,
});
```

In the above, I need to make prevEmployment required and optional if employment.yearsAtJob are >= 2. I see using a descrimatedUnion you can use things like enums. But how do I do a >=2?